# using fiddler export a list of every SOAP action called (.net WCF)

Tags: wcf, soap, fiddler

....using fidler 4.4.9.2

I use fiddler **very seldomly** and just want to know if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I want to export the  to a csv, but I only seem to be able to export the entire header at best using the copy sub-menu. This works but contains a lot of extra "stuff".

Can fiddler do this?  I assume I'll have to write the xpath, at the least, but what feature am I looking for?

Comment: The [Export command on the File menu](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/save-and-load-traffic/tasks/importexportdefault) has more options for export types

Comment: @stuartd thanks.  Exporting to "raw files" actually dumbed just the body, which was exactly what I needed.. although I would have expected the body **and** the headers. A simple console app parsed through the directory o files and I'm happy. Add as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: Are you trying to export the body, or a `SoapAction` header? You could easily copy just the header by exposing it as a column on the Web Sessions list...

Comment: @EricLaw No I was looking for the body.  I am just saying that I would think that an export in "RAW" format would dump the entire thing, headers and the xml/SOAP.  I expected to have to parse out the xml and then run my xpath... It was not what I would expect RAW to mean.

Comment: @Kevcoder: If you're looking for the HTTP Messages (header and body), you simply `Save` them. You use `Export` when you want to change the format or drop information (like the headers). As to wanting the bodies: most SOAP requests carry information about the method called in the `SoapAction` HTTP header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Export command on the File menu](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/save-and-load-traffic/tasks/importexportdefault) has more options for export types:

[image]